# NodeJS API with Kafka back-end

Tags: node.js, rest, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, api-design

I want to build a NodeJS based API that is backed with a pub-sub paradigm with e.g. Kafka. Here is a skeleton of what I want to do.

```js
const express = require('express')
const serverApp = express()
serverApp.get('/book/:bookId', (req, res) => {
    producer.send(JSON.stringify({
        action: 'get',
        message: req.params.bookId
    }))
    consumer.on('message', (data) => {
        res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(data))
    })
})
```

With the option above, the first invocation works but, the subsequent ones keep failing with `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`.

Keeping the `consumer.on` outside of `serverApp.get` will need to have the `req` and `res` co-ordinated.

How do I implement such an API?

Comment: You'll need to unsubscribe every time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example as skeleton

```
const express = require('express')
const serverApp = express()

const responses = Object.create(null);

consumer.on('message', (data) => {
    const result = JSON.parse(data)
    const res = responses[result.replyId]
    res.status(200).send(result)
});

serverApp.get('/book/:bookId', (req, res) => {

    const replyId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);    
    responses[replyId] = res;

    producer.send(JSON.stringify({
        action: 'get',
        replyId,
        message: req.params.bookId
    }))
})
```

Comment: While I try this, `sunstr` should be `substr` and `replyId` should have a key?

Comment: `replyId` is just some unique id. Remove handler must return it back.

Comment: Yes, but, in your `JSON.stringify`, the `replyId` should be key-value pair, right?